# Alongside the Queen, we were delighted to deliver a speech to the MPs - Does anyone know what this means?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Alongside the Queen, we were delighted to deliver a speech to the MPs.

Does this mean

> A) We were delighted to deliver a speech to the MPs and the Queen.

or

> B) The Queen and we were delighted to deliver a speech to the MPs.

?

Comment: Are the Queen and the MPs just placeholders here, standing for any nouns?

Comment: I don't think this is a proper use of *alongside*, though it is hard to say with just one sentence. Seems to me like it should be "Along with the Queen..." or "Besides the queen...".

Comment: Could you give us the context in which you found this sentence? Its meaning is not obvious, and the context may supply the necessary clues.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence means that you were delighted to give the speech to the MP's, but the queen was an observer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the literal meaning is "We were delighted to deliver a speech to the MPs, and when we made the speech we were standing near to the Queen". That is different from both A and B.

The sentence doesn't make much sense to me, as a Brit. The obvious context for "a speech, the Queen, and MPs" would be the state opening of Parliament, but that is a very formal event where the Queen reads out a speech written by the Prime Minister, outlining the legislation for that parliamentary session.

A possible interpretation would be that somebody was deputizing for the Queen (because of illness, etc). That person would probably be another member of the Royal Family (e.g. Prince Charles) who would refer to himself or herself using the "royal plural "we", not "I". But in that case, the Queen would most likely not be there at all.

Answer (score 0):

Its slightly ambiguous, it could have several meanings.

"Alongside the Queen" means that the Queen was present, and standing close to you. She may have given a speech herself. She may have spoken alongside you. She may have been just an observer. You can't tell from this sentence.

You could rewrite it:

> Whilst standing close to the queen, we were pleased to deliver a speech to the MPs.

Comment: It's generally best not to answer a question that's ambiguous unless you can be very sure to thoroughly answer for absolutely all possible cases.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @user3169 - It does provide an answer. The answer is: neither A nor B, or possibly both. It is also useful. "None of the above" is a perfectly valid response.

Answer (score 0):

**Alongside** has at least three possible definitions:

> 1) close to the side of; next to.
>
> "she was sitting alongside him"

This is the definition that other answers are reading: *"Sitting by the queen, we gave a talk to the members of parliament."*

This seems unlikely to me.

> 2) together and in cooperation with.
>
> "I worked alongside him for many weeks"

This usage is unlikely, and I've never seen it used at the beginning of a sentence like this.

> 3) at the same time as or in coexistence with.
>
> "alongside the development of full-time courses there had to be provision for the part-time student"

This third use, while uncommon and I would argue even nonstandard/colloquial, does seem to be the usage that is being used here.

So I believe the meaning is *"I gave a talk to the queen, and was honored that some MPs watched, too."*